# how to implement alphabetic scroll bar in android

Tags: android, scroll, alphabet

i am using fastscroll with indexer, but i want to implement a alphabetic scroll view just similar to Iphone. any idea?

i hope u can take a look at this image[image]

Comment: I need to implement that to. If you can make it, please tell me how to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Just [enable Fast Scroll for your `ListView`](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setFastScrollEnabled%28boolean%29).

Comment: thank u for your post i have implemented enablefast scroll in list view... what i get is First Letter of the contact but all i need is seperate scrollbar of the right have side of the screen... just like a one in iphone.

Comment: Is it possible have alphabetic scrollbar simillar to iphone contacts?

Comment: @Adhavan - I don't have an iPhone so I have no idea what that one is like.  However, if you are developing for an Android phone it makes sense to use standard Android UI elements as that is what users will be used to.  Copying iPhone elements will be confusing for uses when all their other apps use Android ones.

Comment: @ Dave webb: i agree with you.not only in iphone i have also seen this in Samsung Galaxy S devices.i hope u can see that on the youtube http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yclcs338CGc. this is what i exacatly want to implement

Comment: @Adhavan have you got your alphabetic scrollView working? If you have, how you did it?

Comment: @Krishnabhadra: take a look at my answer